# Issue with datatable data, when plus icon show the data changed and reflecting the data integer not the string?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using datatable in my project and when we have more columns and showing plus sign then one of our column have conditional data for status, is showing the data value not the return value.

I want to achieve 
Status : if data is 1 then return active 
if data is 2 then return inactive
if data is 3 then return locked

[image]

```
                    render: function (data, type, row)
                    {
                        if (data == '1') {return 'Active';}
                        else if (data == '2') {return 'Deleted';}
                        else if (data == '3') {return 'Locked';}
                        else if (data == '4') {return 'Dormant';}
                        else if (data == '5') {return 'Expired';}
                        else if (data == '0') {return 'Inactive';}
                    }
                },
```

I want to achieve Active, Inactive, Locked as an status instead of 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 0):

Use `===` to match values and parse integer first if the data is a string to make it work on all possible scenarios

```
{
   if (typeof data === 'string') {
      data = Number(data);
   }
   if (data === 1) {
      return 'Active';
   } else if (data === 2) {
      return 'Deleted';
   } else if (data === 3) {
      return 'Locked';
   } else if (data === 4) {
      return 'Dormant';
   } else if (data === 5) {
      return 'Expired';
   } else if (data === 0) {
      return 'Inactive';
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahil for your effort, Actually problem is in datatable, and when we have more columns, it will move to another row and then data value changed from active to 1